# How To Make Partiton For Windows 10

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted

I am using Ubuntu as my main OS and windows 10 is my secondary OS. I have a 500gb hdd.i want to create a new partition or resize my main Ubuntu partition.

How can I do it? Gparted partition don't give me access to resize my main partition.

[image: GParted Screenshot]

Comment: If in the 'resize`window, drag the handle on the right  of the partition's image to the left, then look if the 'resize' button will become active.

Comment: ubuntu can give me access to drag for sizing and resizing...

Answer (score 0):

To resize partitions it is necessary before dismounting the partitions.
Padlock may not be appearing in GParted.
Boot the system using a live-pendrive.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem had to boot in windows and use the windows partition manager.

Comment: Windows' built-in partition manager cannot resize ex4 file systems that Ubuntu uses. -1